# Customize DatePicker by PerpetuumSoft

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, datepicker

I use UI Controls for Windows 8 by Perpetuum Software.
There is good DatePicker.
But i need some customizations:

1. How to change available range of date that use can select?
2. Month names in Date selector pop-up always in English, but all other text in system language. How to change month name?

Comment: Unfortunately, Perpetuum's software is closed-source, so you'll need to find assistance from people who have the controls or from Perpetuum themselves. Especially for the first one. For the second one, and this may be different based on how they implemented it, you may be able to create a custom Style and use the Multilingual Toolkit, along with a Converter to translate all of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As such the control doesn't support such behavior. The only thing which is possible to do is to monitor date changes by using DateChanged event or by monitoring changes of DependencyProperty Date.
2. The localization issue was fixed in the latest version. Make sure you have the latest version, else it can be downloaded from perpetuumsoft's download page: http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Downloads.aspx?lang=en. For getting the month name value you can use DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName.